# How to create an array that is filled with elements randomly selected from another array

Tags: python, arrays, random

Basically say i have this array d = [1,6,7,4,9] and i want to take that content randomly and fill it into another array using a for loop a certain number of times and print the result
so,

```
d= [1,6,7,4,9]

n = 100

s = []

for i in range(n)

   s[i] = random.choice(d)

print(s)
```

however, I'm getting the error that list assignment is out of range and just wanted to know what would be the best way to get this code to run. My main problem  is appending the random choice into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [random.choice(d) for _ in range(n)]
```

Python does not automatically grow arrays when you use indexing.

Alternatively, you could have started with

```
s = [None] * n
```

so that `s` starts with size `n`, and used the rest of your code.

Comment: okay so i would have to create an empty array of that size then i can fill the array in? okay so that makes a lot of sense because the error was really confusing me for a second.

Comment: Correct.  Or use `append`, which does grow the array, as given in the other answer.  And for simple cases of building a list, list comprehension is often easier to understand and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `s[i] = random.choice(d)` try out `s.append(random.choice(d))`. The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to index parts of the list that don't exist yet.

Comment: so does append grow the array?

Comment: @WeepingWillow Yes. It adds the element to the end of the list.